# how to get JQuery autocomplete option in mouse click?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, autocomplete

I have this coding for getting autocomplete options from database and make a list in that text box. I select few things in drop down list and the from the selected items, im displaying in that textbox. It is working but im facing two problems here.

1. Im getting options only when i start to type in textbox. But i want whenever the textbox is get clicked.
2. And the option list doesn't appear one by one..it shows like a prargraph..3 items per line..But i want it as a list.

   ```
      function SearchText() { 

           $("#<%= EndClient_Txt.ClientID %>").autocomplete({           

               source: function(request, response) { 
               var obj = {};
               obj.pcat = $.trim($("[id*=Cmb_PrdCat]").val());
                obj.domain = $.trim($("[id*=Cmb_Domain]").val());
                obj.region = $.trim($("[id*=Cmb_Reg]").val());

                   $.ajax({  
                       type: "POST",  
                       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
                       url: "SalesOrderInput.aspx/GetClientName",                         
                       data: JSON.stringify(obj),              
                       dataType: "json",  
                       success: function(data) {  
                           response($.map(data.d, function(item) {  
                           return {  
                               value: item  
                           }  
                       }))   
                       },  
                       error: function(result) {  
                           alert("No Match");  
                       }  
                   });  
               }  
           }).on('focus',function(){            

               $(this).keydown();
            });  
     }
   </script>
   ```

**My aspx.vb code**

```
 <Services.WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function GetClientName(ByVal pcat As String, ByVal domain As String, ByVal region As String) As List(Of String)

        Dim empResult As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
        Sql = "SELECT * FROM opportunities where PCategory ='" & pcat & "' and Domain ='" & domain & "' and Region='" & region & "'"


        Dim cmd = New MySqlCommand(Sql, conn1)
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While (reader.Read())
            empResult.Add(reader("OppName").ToString())
        End While
        reader.Close()
        Return empResult
    End Function
```

Optionlist screenshot..
[image]Here totally 6 options are there..but listed in two lines.

Comment: add `minLength` to 0 in autocomplete for issue 1 . [autocomplete](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-minLength)

Comment: I agree with @SaravananN. Can you share screenshot what are you trying to say about second issue. I believe it should be work fine.

Comment: i updated my question with screenshot

Comment: This issue is regarding your CSS. Make sure you have added jQuery-ui CSS and loaded correctly on browser. I have added this [CSS](https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css) and [JS](https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js). It's seems working fine. I can't produce error as shown on your screenshot.

Comment: i downloaded jueryui version1.12.1..but still same problem.

Comment: Then, there must be some design issue, Might be your CSS class override from somewhere. Please disable your custom CSS temporary OR try to create separate project with above details and look what will happen.

Comment: Yes.another CSS file has style as li{ float: left;}..THis changed the autocomplete list . So i added this  li.ui-menu-item {float: none; }. It works fine now.